# What are the max tcod window dimensions

Tags: python

I am making a `tcod` program and then using `pyinstaller` I convert it in an `exe` file. When I try to run the `exe` file, there's an error saying that the window is too large to create.

The exact error is:

```
 File "main.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 44, in main
    with tcod.context.new_terminal(
  File "tcod\_internal.py", line 33, in wrapper
  File "tcod\context.py", line 618, in new_terminal
  File "tcod\context.py", line 571, in new
  File "tcod\_internal.py", line 80, in _check_warn
  File "tcod\_internal.py", line 67, in _check
  File "tcod\_internal.py", line 61, in _raise_tcod_error
RuntimeError: libtcod 1.24.0 libtcod\src\libtcod\renderer_sdl2.c:952
Could not create SDL window:
Window is too large.
```

I want to know the maximum dimensions of a window in tcod.